# Python HTTP server does not send responses

Tags: python, http

Here have two scripts.One is main script and other one for Server Handler.Through the main script Im calling the Handler.
Server will start up but won't be able to send responses.
Please Help me.

**Main script:**

```
def start_server(message_queue):

    print time.asctime(), "Server Start - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT)
    httpd = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST_NAME, PORT), ServerHandler(message_queue))
    httpd.serve_forever()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_PATH, level=LOG_LEVEL, format='%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')

    queue = Queue()
    process_new = Process(target=start_server, args=(queue,))
    process_new.start()
    queue.put("INSUFFICIENT_CREDIT")
```

**Server Handler :**

```
class ServerHandler(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, message_queue):
         self.queue = message_queue


    def do_POST(self,message_queue):
        message = message_queue.get()
        if message is None:
            print "Test result"
        else:
            "SUCCESS"

        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
```

Comment: Did you get any errors ? In which case, it is useful to post them too.

Comment: Can you confirm the PID of the new process is running?

Comment: When we run the script it says "ServerHandler instance has no __call__ method".Therefore I added a call method,then the error is no longer present but still didn't get the response from the server.

Comment: While running the Main script once the server start is printing Host name and the port like Fri Sep 12 14:03:18 2014 Server Start - 192.168.0.193:8001 this.In the terminal you can grep for that process, using netstat -nlp | grep 8001.Result would be like tcp        0      0 192.168.0.193:8001      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3868/python2.7 .Means server is listening.